# App published on the stores ENV_TEST is true

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I used this within my app:

```
if(ENV_DEVELOPMENT) {
    Ti.API.info('Environment: DEVELOPMENT');
    alert('Environment: DEVELOPMENT');
}else if(ENV_TEST) {
    Ti.API.info('Environment: TEST');
    alert('Environment: TEST');
}else if(ENV_PRODUCTION) {
    Ti.API.info('Environment: PRODUCTION');
}
```

The App has just been published in the stores and it's alerting 'Environment: TEST'.

Is there any reason why a published app should give ENV_TEST = true??

Comment: iOS or Android?  Also, what SDK version?

Comment: 5.5.1 and iOS. Android hasn't gone live on the store yet so I can't see if that's not working.